Flexible page layout (dynamic region insertion)
Is there a way to let editors while inserting components into a page, to insert regions instead of forcing predefined regions to the page? It would be helpful to allow editors to select from allowed list of regions to insert on the page

Unfortunately, this is not possible. I had the same idea a while ago, you can find it on the Tridion Ideas site. If you - and others - would vote for it, maybe it will find its way into the product some day.
See https://community.rws.com/ideas/tridion-ideas/i/tridion-sites-ideas/allow-editors-to-insert-regions-into-a-page.

It is really needed, it will reduce number of CTs and development effort. It does not have to be like fully dynamic site builder, allowing the user to insert predefind regions as many as they wish into the page would be enough I think and should make the life easier. Thanks @Quirijn

Agreed that this would be a very useful feature.  For the time being, you could have a look at a DXA Module which solves the problem to some extent: https://community.rws.com/product-groups/tridion/tridion-sites/b/techweblog/posts/dxa-container-framework-v1-1
